# What online backup solutions work with Linux?

Tags: linux, backup

I'm looking for an **online** backup solution for my Ubuntu server. Unfourtunatly it looks like both mozy and backblaze do not have a linux client?

The paid version of dropbox does have a linux client, but I would be struggling to fit all my photos on it (Im shooting RAW files) and it starts at double the price of Mozy/Backblaze

What are my options?

Comment: The current solution im tending towards is running a windows VM, rsyncing to it and running mozy. Feature/price wise mozy is just so much better that most of the competition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) is my advice. It has many backup options. It lets you do backup to a folder, another network computer, a friend's computer or to CrashPlan's own backup server. Just find a friend with enough hard drive space and you can get your files out of the house for free. It's also very easy to set up.

Answer (score 3):

[JungleDisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/) supports linux and will happily backup all your data to a variety of services such as Amazon S3 and Rackspace Cloud Files.

> Jungle Disk Desktop Edition lets you store files and automatically backup all of your data easily and securely to Rackspace Cloud Files and Amazon S3.
>
> - Store an unlimited amount of data for only 15¢ per GB
> - Pay only for what you use, no commitment
> - Your data is fully encrypted at all times
> - Multiple datacenters to ensure high availability
> - Automatically backup important files quickly and easily

Comment: at 7.50 per 50GB its a bit cheaper than dropbox, still considerably more expensive than mozy ...

Comment: This is as good as you will find. It is using high availability platforms like S3. It is highly unlikely that you would find a service that is as fast as Amazon S3 and still be able to store unlimited data.

Comment: yerp, it looks like one of the cheapest options.

Comment: I've been very happy with it for desktop stuff for about a year. The current pricing is a monthly $2 + storage/bandwidth fees (15 cents/GB storage).

Answer (score 3):

[**UbuntuOne**](https://one.ubuntu.com/) is also [something to check out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One).

> Ubuntu One is a [storage application and service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_hosting_service) operated by Canonical Ltd and currently in public beta.
>
> The Ubuntu One service is similar to services such as [ZumoDrive](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ZumoDrive&action=edit&redlink=1), [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(storage_provider)), [Box.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box.net), Mozy, [Wuala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wuala), [Humyo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humyo) and [Live Mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Mesh). Its client code is implemented in Python. It uses Twisted for its low-level networking, and Protocol Buffers for protocol description. What sets Ubuntu One apart from the other similar service providers is the integration with other services: Evolution for contacts, Tomboy for notes.
>
> <sup>Canonical has been criticized for abuse of the Ubuntu trademark for commercial exploitation, and for launching a proprietary service.</sup>

Comment: It was announced today that [Ubuntu One is shutting down](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) on June 1, 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a bit outside of the box but were you to use a web hosting service that grants shell access you could simply rsync and achieve the same result.  I do something right along those lines with [Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com/) as I get unlimited disk space with them for about seven bucks a month...

Comment: very interesting out-of-the-box thinking, with duplicity you can even make this solution support history.

Comment: Careful: many hosting providers prohibit the use of *hosting* space for *backup* purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com). On Linux, Windows and OSX.

2Gb are free, you have a revision history for every file and you are able to undelete files. The real bonus for me is that it is fast. I tried some other products as well, but Dropbox consistently used the fewest bandwidth and processor time of everything I tried. They say that this is so since Dropbox uses file system notifications instead of manual indexing and only uploads diffs instead of whole files.
Whatever, I love it, it never failed me and saved my buttocks more than once!

Answer (score 2):

[Comparison Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_backup_services) of all available online services. Hope you can find a better one with the comparison :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [CloudBerry Backup for Linux](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/backuplinux.aspx). You just need to have your cloud storage account (I went for Amazon S3, but they support Azure too) to start your automated backup. If you schedule it, it will back up your photos automatically. The price is indeed good. You pay some pennies for GBs of data and pay once for a CloudBerry life-long license.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a similar question I posted on ServerFault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/31828/duplicity-and-amazon-s3-script

Basically, you can use duplicity in a script to automatically (and securely) backup your files to Amazon's S3 service.