# Mesh-like service for SSH?

Tags: ssh, windows-live-mesh

Has anyone heard of a service like Microsoft Mesh except for SSH rather than Remote Desktop?

Normal SSH doesn't work via Web proxy, Mesh does. But I find Remote Desktop too slow and would prefer SSH access to my home network.

Comment: What OS? If only linux, take a look at the answers on http://superuser.com/questions/65983/what-online-backup-solutions-work-with-linux

Comment: My understanding of MS Mesh is that is it a synchronisation system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Mesh). What are you trying to sync?

Comment: There are ways to use ssh over web proxies ( more detailed here http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/ssh3_inhalt.en.html but be sure not to violate your companies policies). But there is no better alternative to connect to a linux/unix box remotely.

Comment: @Doug Any OS. @David Mesh also offers Remote Desktop. @Mugen I don't think SSHing to my home machine is a problem when Remote Desktopping isn't.

Comment: @Doug Those are online backup solutions. I want SSH.

Comment: @Mugen I'm not sure the client is available for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) has a built-in ability to go through a web proxy.

Go to the Connection -> Proxy screen, select HTTP for the Proxy type, and provide the hostname and port.  Provide a username and password if required by your proxy.

Some web proxies will refuse to connect you to any port except 443 because they are intended for HTTPS connections.  SSH being port 22 normally, this poses a problem.  You may consider moving your SSH server to port 443 in this case.

Comment: OpenSSH (the usual implementation on unix) can also connect via a proxy, with the `ProxyCommand` option. The manual has an example using OpenBSD netcat; instead of netcat you can use `corkscrew` or `connect-proxy` if you have them.

Comment: I'll check this out. Ta.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! This works. Just to be on the safe side I set up a minimal Linux VM to act as gatekeeper. I configured sshd to listen on port 443. Works.